# How to install/reinstall commands in Mac terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal

I always run into problems with my terminal because the command I'm trying to use is "not found". Then when I try to install that command I have another command that is also "not found" that I need to install. Also whenever I get something like sudo it works for that session but next time I open terminal I have to reinstall the commands all over. If I do

```
echo $PATH
```

It returns

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:’/usr/local/bin:??
```

I received a temporary solution which works decently but I have to redo everytime I open terminal so if someone could explain to me how to fix this permanently  that would be great. I know echo $PATH isnt supposed to return that.

Comment: Yes that is copied and pasted form terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to uninstall or reinstall any commands, you probably just need to fix whatever's causing your `PATH` variable to get corrupted.

To set it to reasonable defaults for the current shell session, type this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Note that this only fixes it for the current shell session, and the next Terminal window you open will be back to the broken state.

To fix it for next time, you'll need to find where it's getting set wrong and fix it there.

In modern macOS, system-wide path stuff is set up in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*` (those are text-based config files). So check those first and make sure they look sane.

Also, there are system-wide shell startup scripts in `/etc/`, such as `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`, among others. It's fairly common to set or add to your `PATH` in shell startup scripts. If you, or some installer or package manager or install script has edited those, you may need to see what it did and fix it (that is, view those script files in a text editor and edit them to fix them if you find mistakes). Which ones you need to check depend on which shells you're using, how you're invoking and using them (i.e. as login, non-login interactive, or non-interactive shells), and which shell startup script files exist (some take precedence over others, so the presence of some files may cause other files not to get run). You'll need to check the man pages for the shells you're using for details on which shell startup scripts they run in which situations.

Then you need to check your own personal shell startup scripts in your own home directory. Again, which scripts get run depend on which shell you use, how you're invoking it, and which script files exist, so you need to check the man pages. You'll probably end up needing to look at `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

One last note: Assuming you copy/pasted that output text, it looks like it contains a curly quote, which suggests one of your shell startup scripts accidentally contains a curly quote. Be careful of editing shell scripts and other computer-readable text-based file formats (source code, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, .plists, etc.) in GUI word processors / text editors. Make sure to turn off all the text substitution features like "smart quotes" and "smart dashes" or you'll end up accidentally getting curly quotes where you wanted a straight quote, or an em dash where you wanted two hyphens. Most computer-readable formats only consider straight quotes to be syntactically meaningful.

Comment: -bash: /etc/paths: Permission denied  -bash: /etc/paths.d/40-XQuartz: Permission denied

Comment: I just typed those in as you typed them but should I run a command on them? If I do ls they return different things

Comment: ls /etc/paths
/etc/paths

Comment: @TylerBloom Those are text files. You want to edit them with a text editor with root privileges. So for example if you know how to use `vi`, you could `sudo vi /etc/paths`.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what a text editor is. If I run sudo vi it returns 
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~ ~  ~  ~ ~ ~ ~  ~  ~ ~  ~ ~~ ~  ~  ~ ~ ~   ~  "/etc/paths" 5L, 45C  each ~  on a seperate line though

Comment: @TylerBloom Given your questions so far, I think you would benefit from taking some kind of "Unix basics" or "shell basics" tutorial. If you keep trying to blunder your way through, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @TylerBloom A text editor is a program for editing text documents. Like programmers and Unix sysadmins use. A word processor like Microsoft Word is like a super fancy text editor that can do fonts and styled text and graphics spellcheck and all sorts of other stuff programmers don't need. A text editor is like a bare-bones word processor for plain unstyled ASCII text.

Comment: Yeah I'll see if that exists I still don't even understand what I'm doing so I wouldn't know where to look for understanding this stuff. If I open etc/paths with TextEdit I get a file saying /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

Comment: But if I open a new terminal window it still has /opt/local/bin... etc in echo $PATH

Comment: So terminal is a part of Unix?

Comment: @TylerBloom I think it's much more likely the problem is in one of your personal shell startup files (the ones in `~/`) than the system-wide ones (in `/etc/`), so look at those first. Also, in addition to `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, check `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`. You can view them with `more` (e.g. `more ~/.profile`). Look for curly quotes! From the resulting `$PATH`, I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: The problem was that my PATH was messed up. What exactly would I be checking in bashrc, profile, and bash_profile? None of them are in my home directory (~) right now but that could just be because it's still messed up. If I figure out where those are I will try. I'm taking a Unix tutorial right now.

Comment: @TylerBloom Are you sure they're not in your home folder? Note that those filenames all start with a period, which means they're generally invisible. `ls ~` will not show them, but `ls -A ~` will.

Comment: @TylerBloom What you're looking for is commands like `PATH=something` where the "something" includes fancy quotes.

Comment: ls ~/.bashrc
ls: /Users/tyler1313/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: What are fancy quotes?